# Byte regex matching with Boost in C++

Tags: c++, regex, boost, match

I am using the Boost lib for regex matching. 
My input "string" in which I want to search is not actually 
a string but more a bitmap, which may contain any byte.

The matching works fine as long as there are no
Null bytes within the input string. If there is a 
Null byte, everything after it is ignored.

This code works if I replace the null byte:

```
char* expr = ".*\\x08\\x00\\x27\\x47\\x6b\\xd4.*"
char data[] = {0x12, 0x08, 0x00, 0x27, 0x47, 0x6b, 0xd4, 0x08 }
boost::regex regex = boost::regex(expr);
boost::cmatch what;
if(boost::regex_match(data, what, regex)) 
  //found match
  ... 
else 
  // failure did not match
  ...
```

Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Comment: This looks much more like a fixed-string search than a regular expression matching.

Comment: This is just for prove of concept, I really want to use it for regex matching...the error would be there in both cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like `regex_match()` is treating your `char` arrays as null-terminated strings, and ingoring everything past the `0x00`.  `regex_match()` will also work with `std::string` types, which don't have null-terminators.  Have you tried representing your data in that manner?

Comment: I just tried passing a string and I get the following
error:  no matching function for call to ‘regex_match(std::string&, boost::cmatch&, boost::regex&)’.

Comment: ... or, if you don't want the expense of putting your data into a `std::string`, use the overload that takes a pair of iterators instead of the single `char const *` parameter. You can pass `data, data + sizeof(data)` as iterators to designate your range.

Answer (score 1):

Boost Regex can also be used to match binary patterns in binary text. It is not confused by control characters like the zero byte.

There are [several](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/basic_regex.html) [overloads](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_64_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/regex_match.html) for the `boost::regex` constructor and the `boost::regex_match` function, e.g. ones that take a `std::string`, a null-terminated C-string - and - overloads for iterator-ranges.

Since we want to also match zero bytes, we obviously can't use null-terminated C-strings. Using `std::string` is possible (because it may contain zero bytes) - but copying the pattern and text just for the search is wasteful.

Iterator-ranges are a perfect fit for this use-case.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/regex.hpp>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{   
  const unsigned char expr[] = {
    '.', '*', 0x08, 0x00, 0x27, 0x47, 0x6b, 0xd4, '.', '*' } ;
  const unsigned char data[] = {
    0x12, 0x08, 0x00, 0x27, 0x47, 0x6b, 0xd4, 0x08 };
  boost::regex regex(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(expr),
      reinterpret_cast<const char*>(expr) + sizeof expr);
  boost::cmatch what;
  if (boost::regex_match(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(data),
        reinterpret_cast<const char*>(data) + sizeof data, what, regex))
    cout << "match!\n";
  else 
    cout << "no match\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Compile via e.g.:

```
$ g++ regex.cc -o regex -Wall -g -lboost_regex
```

Example output:

```
$ ./regex
match!
```

The `reinterpret_cast`s may look dangerous but it is all defined behavior. Note that defining the `data` array as a `char` array isn't a good idea because char may be signed or unsigned depending on the architecture. And when it is signed the `0xd4` yields this error:

```
error: narrowing conversion of ‘212’ from ‘int’ to ‘char’ 
  inside { } [-Wnarrowing]
```

Similar issues are expected when trying to use something like `"\xd4"` in a string literal. With the double backslash the escape is interpreted by Boost regex which easily gets confused like this: 'Hexadecimal escape sequence terminated prematurely'.

Thus, just using an unsigned char array like in the example is the simplest solution.